# Bootstrap API vs Semantic UI API Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api, twitter-bootstrap-3, semantic-ui

I am using the Bootstrap framework on my website. Under you can see some js used with semantic, and I want to do something similar in bootstrap.

some of the file: base.js

```
$.fn.api.settings.api = {
    'get_user': '/api/v1/user/{username}',
};
```

search form in html file:

```
<div id="check_points" class="ui form">
    <form>
        <div class="field username">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <button class="ui submit button">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div class="ui response hidden"></div>
</div>
```

end of html file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#check_points .submit.button')
.api({
    action: 'get_user',
    beforeSend: function(settings) {
        settings.urlData = {
            username: $('#check_points div.field.username input').val()
        };
        return settings;
    },
    successTest: function(response) {
        return response.error == false || true;
    },
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        var el = $('#check_points .response');
        el.addClass('message green');
        el.removeClass('red');
        el.html('User <a href="/user/' + response.username + '"><strong class="username">' + response.username + '</strong></a> has <strong class="points">' + response.points + '</strong> points and is ranked <strong class="rank">' + response.rank + '</strong>.');
        if (el.hasClass('hidden')) {
            el.transition({
                animation: 'slide down',
                duration: '500ms',
            });
        }
    },
    onFailure: function(response) {
        var el = $('#check_points .response');
        el.addClass('message red');
        el.removeClass('green');
        el.html('No user with the name <strong class="username">XXX</strong> found.');
        el.find('strong.username').text($('#check_points div.field.username input').val());
        if (el.hasClass('hidden')) {
            el.transition({
                animation: 'slide down',
                duration: '500ms',
            });
        }
    }
});
</script>
```